# Undefined name user

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 screens, login, homepage and chat. In chat I want to use user, but for some reasons I am getting an error.

Error in HomePage class while trying to pass user to the Chat: 'Undefined name 'user''.

Here samples of code:

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  String email;
  String password;

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  
  Future<String> login(String _email, String _password) async {
    FirebaseUser user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _email, password: _password))
        .user;
    () =>
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Bar(user: user)));
  }
 ...
```

Why is it not defined? I want to pass *user* from Login(), through Homepage() to the Chat().
Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**
I noticed it is not defined only in List, but besides it works properly.
How can I pass it to the list?

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final FirebaseUser user;

  const HomePage({Key key, this.user}) : super(key:key);

  @override
  _BarState createState() => _BarState();
}


class _BarState extends State<HomePage> {

  void test() {
    () =>
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
Chat(user: widget.user))); < ---- WORKING
  }

  int tabIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> widgetOptions = [
    Match(),
    Chat(user: widget.user), < --- NOT WORKING
    AddBook(),
    Profile(),
  ];
```

Comment: we can't see the whole code.

Comment: Can you show us what your `Chat class` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you want to access user object in other screen, instead of passing it in cconstructor, create a singleton class, Like this

```
class AuthUser {
  static var authUserId;
  static var email;
  static var userName;
  static var role;
  static var companyId;
}
```

During login Set values like this, please check here print(user); and set value respectively

```
Future<String> login(String _email, String _password) async {
    FirebaseUser user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _email, password: _password))
        .user;
    () =>
AuthUser.email = user.email,
AuthUser.email = user.userName,
..........
       ));
  }
```

Access data in other screens like, AuthUser.email, AuthUser.userName.....

Comment: That's great idea, but how can I set password? AuthUser.password = user.password doesn't work, probably for safety reasons

Comment: Yes, its for safety reason, but you could try like AuthUser.password = password, you are getting password from user during login

Comment: Hello, I just got back to the code and I don't need password variable in Chat at all, I used only email, thanks for solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use Chat(user: widget.user) instead.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it partially works, but not in my case. I updated question

Answer (score 0):

when you are using a stateful widgets and what to get properties from constructor you need to do it like this:

`widget.varNameInConstructor`

most of the time it's not needed but if you want to assign that to you own new variable in state you can do it at initState.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it partially works, but not in my case. I updated question